# Why this Javascript code fails in IE7-8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this code:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

  var li_list = document.getElementById("topmenu").getElementsByTagName("li");

  for (var i=0; i<li_list.length; i++) {

      li_list[i].onmouseover=function() {
          this.className+=" hover";
      }

      li_list[i].onmouseout=function() {
          this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" hover\\b"), "");
      }
  }
})
```

In IE7-8 it fails: document.getElementById(...) is null or not an object.

In Firefox it works well.

That affect the main menu function of the site: http://paraguasparados.com

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think IE has a 'domready' event. You should probably use a library like jQuery, MooTools, Prototype, ExtJS, ender, Dojo, etc.

Comment: Double check that the element specified "topmenu" matches case, some versions of IE are case-insensitive on Id names, but the newer versions are not...

Comment: Thanks @Sparky, but the case is correct. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Possibly the DOM is not ready when it is called.   Another gotcha is that IE version of getDocumentById also looks at the name property.  Any reason not to use JQUERY's Ready() method which is more reliable across browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On IE, domready can fire before the dom is actually ready. [Post.](http://www.sigsiu.net/forum/community-board-for-troubleshooting-problems/internet-explorer-dom-readiness-problem-and-solution-explained/)

So then `document` object is not yet available when your code is executed. (Hence the IE error message "document.getElementById(...) is null or not an object.")

Solution: use a toolkit (jQuery, yui, etc) to provide the equivalent of domready that works on IE and other browsers.

Comment: Good answer since you are telling why it isn't working, and not just suggesting another approach to make it work.

Comment: Thanks @Larry, the link that you provided was very useful. Now I understand and the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks for the check @Memochipan, you pushed me over 7K! I'm happy to have been of help to you.

Comment: one important note from the article quoted as Post: if you use mootools, replace domready with load, because ie domready is unreliable.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead. This should only work in IE though.

```
document.attachEvent( "onreadystatechange", function() {
    if ( document.readyState === "complete" ) {
        // dom ready
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @William, you're right that works in IE but not in Firefox. Can you explain why?

Comment: IE uses `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`. Here is a cross browser dom ready function if you want. [http://jsfiddle.net/CdKsx/](http://jsfiddle.net/CdKsx/).

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery, they have done the leg work getting it to work cross browser.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// do some stuff here
});
```

Comment: true, but mootools hasn't, and with cms like joomla, sometimes you can't substitute jQuery without rewriting lot of code